# using .read() from a specific part of file

Tags: python, file

I have a file, a part of which im willing to read using .read(). I know exactly how much bytes i want to read from file and from what point of file i should start. For example if have X mb file and i want to .read() from 10523 byte to 15523 byte of it. How do i set .read() to actually read what i want? Thank you for your time and im sorry if that question is asked somewhere out there already(didnt find any after a brief search).

Ive tried to find something in documentation as well as in google or here.

Comment: `f.seek(start); f.read(end-start)`. You can read about `file` objects and their methods here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position the file pointer manually (rather than always reading from the position following the most recently read data) using the `seek` method.

```
f.seek(10523)
x = f.read(5000)
```

Comment: That seems like something i was looking for! Thanks alot! Im still starting to learn python so it always good to have some place where i can ask questions.